# Perl remove truncating zeros from strings/floating point numbers

Tags: regex, perl, truncate

In the below example I am trying to ignore all cases where str1 equals str2 i.e str1 eq str2. Below is the issue I am facing.

**case1 :** str1 = '{V1 0.85}' str2 = '{V1 0.850000}'

**case2 :** str1 = '{V1 0.65} {V2 off} {V_3 1.1}' str2 = '{V1 0.650000} {V2 off} {V_3 1.100000}'

**case3 :** str1 = '{V2 0.0} {V3 2.0} {V4 ON}' str2 = '{V2 0.0000000} {V3 2.000000} {V4 ON}'

Each of the above examples should satisfy the condition str1 =str2 if trailing 0's are removed from the string.

Currently this is the regex I am using :

```
$str2 =~ s/\.?0*}/\}/;
```

But it works only in some cases.
Example for case 2 above it removes zeros in the 1st {} but not the 2nd set i.e

**Before:** str1 is '{v_0p65 0.65} {vout_off off} {v_1p1 1.1}'

**After** using regex is  '{v_0p65 0.65} {vout_off off} {v_1p1 1.100000}'

Code is something like below(Too complex to paste one small snippet):
str1 and str2 are exact outputs of 2 hashes which are received iteratively
The code is simply

```
if ($str1 eq $str2) { 
 #Don't do anything
else {
print ("str1 and str2 are not equal\n");
}
```

Comment: Can you include the actual code you are using?

Comment: Just added above.. Quite a complex code that requires several input files. But is something exactly like above for this part. So pretty much all I need is a regex to convert str2 to str1 somehow

Comment: If you do not post your _actual_ code, we cannot give you an _actual_ solution. Currently your `if`  statement demo code will purely match if `$str1 equals `$str2` then do nothing unless it does not match. which in anyways would be better written as `unless ($str1 eq $str2) { print ...;`

Comment: `$RE{num}{real}` => https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp::Common

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
s/ \K0*([0-9]+\.[0-9]+?)0*(?=})/$1/g;
```

In English, between a space and a }, remove leading zeros before the decimal point (not including a zero just before the decimal point) and trailing zeros at the end (not including a zero just after the decimal point).

`/g` makes it operate as many times as it can in the same string.  That seems to be the key part you were missing, though your substitution had other problems too.

Comment: Thanks a lot that was exactly what I was looking for. I used this in my code s/([0-9]+\.[0-9]*[1-9]*?)0*/$1/g..What does \K in your version do?

Comment: ` \K` is a more efficient equivalent to `(?<= )`; it checks that there is a space before.  ` \K0*` can be left out if you never need to remove leading 0s

Comment: `[0-9]*?` is a more efficient way to say `[0-9]*[1-9]*` (in this particular case); the `?` makes it prefer to include 0s at the end in the 0* instead.

Comment: Your regex is not right, it doesn't change `1.20300` or `2.000000`